# How to send a model property value from a view to controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a view tied with a Item model that displays a shopping item. I want to a add a quantity text field and submit the itemID and quantity to a controller. I am using an AJAX form.

AJAX form:

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("AddToCart", "PizzaBasket",
new AjaxOptions
{
    InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
    HttpMethod = "GET",
    OnFailure = "searchFailed",
    LoadingElementId = "ajax-loader",
    UpdateTargetId = "basketSummary",
})) 
{
@Html.HiddenFor(id => id.ItemId, new { @class = "id" })
<input type="hidden" name="id" class="id")/>
<label for="quantity">Quantity</label>
<input type="text" name="quantity" size="5"/>
<input type="submit" value="Add to Cart" />
<img id="ajax-loader" src="@Url.Content("~/Content/Images/ajax-loader.gif")" style="display:none"/> 
}
```

Controller action:

```
 public ActionResult AddToCart(String id, String quantity) {
 /*Add to cart*/
 return RedirectToAction("Index");           
}
```

However, the id value is not getting submitted. Need to find out how to pass the id value from the AJAX form to the controller. Please note, that in the same file @Model.itemId is working fine.

Comment: Most certain issue is that you have a ")" in your hidden id markup, that would make your html tag invalid, and the final result is the same as if the hidden never been there :)

Answer (score 0):

This line:

```
@Html.HiddenFor(id => id.ItemId, new { @class = "id" })
```

needs to be inside your Using statement. The same goes for your submit button/input. In order for the ajax form to submit properly those two must be inside the Using block.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Forms Collection as follows,

View :

```
@Html.HiddenFor(m=>m.ProductID)
```

Controller:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public void HiddenForExample(FormCollection collection)
    {
        string productid = Convert.ToString(collection["ProductID"]);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the control that will post the `id` to your controller (and take note of the parentheses, it should be removed):

```
<input type="hidden" name="id" class="id") />
```

It is this control that the model binder will use to populate the `String id` argument in your controller action. Since you are hard-coding it, the only way to manipulate its value prior to posting to the controller is with javascript. Are you certain you are doing that? Otherwise the value will come across as empty.

Also, for your Ajax options, you should set your method to post:

```
HttpMethod = "POST"
```

I can't see what HTML Action your particular controller action expects, but I'm guessing it has been decorated with `[HttpPost]`